# Foreign characters in the installation path - Installshield Installscript project

Tags: installshield, installscript

I have a strange problem which surfaces intermittently. The installer installs fine but the installation path has foreing characters. This is a pure English US language installer.

This is what I do:

> g_szProductBaseDir = g_szCompanyBaseDir ^ IFX_PRODUCT_NAME;

where,

> g_szCompanyBaseDir  = D:\Program Files\ABC\
>
> IFX_PRODUCT_NAME = Hardware\VMC567-CIRCLE

The special characters embed themselves before IFX_PRODUCT_NAME. In the end we have an install path with an extra folder with foreign character name.

The log says:

> D:\Program Files\ABC\??\Hardware\VMC567-CIRCLE

Can anyone give me some pointer on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need two backslashes for paths, otherwise you will have characters being escaped. Also, you'll probably need to put g_szProductBaseDir into LongPathToQuote() before you can use it:

```
g_szProductBaseDir = g_szCompanyBaseDir ^ IFX_PRODUCT_NAME;
LongPathToQuote(g_szProductBaseDir, TRUE);
```